# Magento theme development from the base theme files?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Hi I am a beginner in magento,

And I have created the new magento theme for project.

I have created following folders & files for magento theme.

1. package / theme / layout (page.xml, local.xml)
2. package / theme / template / page (.phtml files)

As inside template folder, I have created only page folder and under that html folder.

**EDIT 1**

Also, I added products in magento from the backend. ***Now please help me to understand that

how would i show those products on home page. And also should i copy the files from base folder into new theme folder or something else.***

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin panel -> Cms->pages-> home page  and add this code there

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Now refresh your cache.

Comment: manoj : thanks for reply, but i do not have that page in my theme. catalog/product/list.phtml. so what should i do for that

Comment: Products is not coming

Comment: Login to your admin panel and make changes to home page and check if changes are reflecting in front end.

Comment: Can you tell me whether i should copy all files from the base to new theme. This is my main concern